# jfxtras LocalDatePicker. How to highlight Date

Tags: javafx, highlight, jfxtras

I'm using jfxtras 8.0.r5 library and I have to pre-highlight some LocalData that become from another part of the program so user can see which data are important.

so I use this:

```
LocalDatePicker lLocalPickerADI = new LocalDatePicker();
```

And I put into a Grid and it correctly appear:

```
Grid_Date.add(lCalendarPickerADI,0,1);
```

I have this Observable List where I have the data that I want pre-higlight:

```
public  ObservableList<LocalDate> ADI_DATE=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

filled and passed from other part of code.

So my question is: How I can pre-highligt on the LocalDatePicker? I need to do this from code and not from UI.

sorry if I'm not clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JFXtras LocalDatePicker has a highlightedLocalDates list, in that you can put the to-be-highlighted dates. If you have (too) many of them, you can use the localDateRangeCallback to populate only the required dates for a displayed range.

http://jfxtras.org/doc/8.0/jfxtras-controls/jfxtras/scene/control/LocalDatePicker.html

Comment: lCalendarPickerADI.highlightedLocalDates().addAll(Anal.ADI_DATE);